# memcached.new with the localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached

$cache = Memcached.new("localhost:11211")

I am not quite sure what why do we need the localhost:11211.Is the number 11211 is the port the app is running?  Does that mean all the cache is available for this instance of the app running. what if I leaving it blank.

can anybody explain this to me.

Comment: yes.memcached runs on that port.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 11211 refers to the port on which memcached accepts connections.

It is not however specific to the instance of your app; any app that you run could theoretically connect to memcached on that same port, provided they have the proper credentials.

Comment: so 11211 is the port that memcached running on, not the application itself correct? It says localhost, what about in production? also will 11211 change in production?

Comment: Yes, 11211 is the port on which memcached accepts inbound connections. It's the default choice, so will likely be the same in production unless your configuration specifies otherwise.